# Facebook Javascript sdk, need to press login button twice

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, sdk, facebook-login

I have a Facebook login button with a onclick event.

```
<fb:login-button scope="email, user_about_me, user_birthday" onclick="login()">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

Code if you click it:

```
function login(){
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
   if (response.status === "connected") {
        FB.api({
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT name, email, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid=me()'
                },
        function(response) {
            var check = $.get("includes/facebook_login.php", {command:response[0].email, commandP:response[0].pic_square}, //check if users exist with some selects and create sessions 
                function(data){
                    if(data == 1){ //on facebook_login.php echo 1 if user exists in our db. if so, redirect.
                        FB.Dialog.remove(FB.Dialog._active);
                         window.location="wishlist.php";
                    }
                    else if(data == 0){
                        $("#fb_error").dialog("open");  
                        }
                     });
                }
            );
        }
}, true);
```

}

Code fires the Facebook login without problems. But if this code is done, it won't redirect me to the next page (wishlist.php). I need to click the login button from Facebook again and then it will redirect me. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You’re assuming the login button is done with the login immediately, which it is *not*. So your function `login` gets called before the login has actually taken place.

My suggestion would be: Just throw `<fb:login-button>` over board completely, implement FB.login, and call it on click of a button of your own …